# Newly created Folder is not found by content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I Used this below code to display list of video for a specific folder , when i create that folder programmatically unable to found videos for (Newly Create Folder) specific folder  in content provider .

Code :

```
String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%FolderName%"};
        videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Folder Creation Code:

`String ap = getdata.getString("edit", ""); //Folder Name 'FolderName'
                        path = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ap)
                                .getAbsolutePath().toString());
                        if(!path.exists()){
                            path.mkdir();}`

Comment: How did you create folder. Please post code for that section also.

Comment: Please follow the example given here for "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

Comment: Please provide the Solution don't share the Link Please :)

Comment: I am not sure your code is creating folder or not. It is better to use official document code. Read carefully solution is there only